# not authorized for query on orion.*

Tags: fiware-orion

I have some issue with orion db, which outputs errors like:

```
time=2015-01-13T14:42:19.272UTC | lvl=ERROR |
trans=1421070784-640-00000009856 | function=processContextElement |
comp=Orion | msg=MongoCommonUpdate.cpp[1604]: Database Error (error
retrieving _id field
in doc: { $err: "not authorized for query on orion.entities", code: 16550 })
```

Also I can produce similar error in this way:

```
> use orion
switched to db orion
> db.csubs.find()
error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on orion.csubs", "code" : 16550
}
```

The context broker configuration seems to be without any authentication to
orion database.
/etc/sysconfig/contextBroker has user name and password hashed to database:

```
#BROKER_DATABASE_USER=orion
#BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD=orion
```

Unhashed config not works with db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your MongoDB instance runs with authentication enabled. Thus, there are two solutions:

1. Run MongoDB without authentication, e.g. without `--auth` option. Please, check MongoDB official documentation about this. If you can secure MongoDB access by other means (e.g. fiwarelling) or if security is not relevant at all in your environment (e.g. testing environment), this is probably the simpler option.
2. Set the BROKER_DATABASE_USER and BROKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD parameters to the ones with access permissions to the Orion DB (typically the databased named `orion` if you run CB with default settings). I guess the right user/password should be provided by your database administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion. Indeed mongo was configred with auth. I hashed auth=true option in mongodb.conf and now it works correctly.
Thank You